# Enabling disk encryption fails for Azure Ubuntu 16.04-LTS saying "'VolumeType' is not supported"

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, encryption, azure-powershell

[Azure Disk Encryption for Windows and Linux IaaS VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption) says that "Linux OS disk encryption is currently supported on ... Ubuntu 16.04" however when I create a new VM

```
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName "vmname" -VMSize "Standard_D2_v2"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Linux -ComputerName "vmname" -Credential $cred
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName "Canonical" -Offer "UbuntuServer" -Skus "16.04-LTS" -Version "latest"
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$osDiskUri = $storage_account.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/vmname.vhd"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "myOsDisk1" -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -Location "East US" -VM $vm
```

and then run

```
Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -VMName "vmname" -AadClientID "appname" -AadClientSecret "xxx=" -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl $KeyVault.VaultUri -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $KeyVault.ResourceId;
```

then I get this error:

```
Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AzureDiskEncryptionForLinux'. Error message: "VolumeType "" is not supported".
StartTime: 6/01/2017 3:12:44 PM
EndTime: 6/01/2017 3:14:49 PM
OperationID: b976c3ab-fe5b-4356-b62f-96f3b80aeba1
```

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdaded92-b8ef-4c84-8060-675071a11262/volumetype-is-not-supported?forum=AzureDiskEncryption) suggests there may be some way to apply encryption earlier than this, but actually I think it relates to people with already-encrypted drives they are trying to move into Azure.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I use PowerShell to enable disk encryption on Ubuntu?

Comment: Linux OS disk does not support use cmdlet `Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension` to encrypt.

Answer (score -1):

For now, Azure does not support use `Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension` to encrypt Linux OS disk. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.compute/v2.2.0/set-azurermvmdiskencryptionextension)

> -VolumeType
>
> Specifies the type of virtual machine volumes to perform the encryption operation. Allowed values for virtual machines that run the Windows operating system are as follows: All, OS, and Data.
>
> **The allowed values for Linux virtual machines are as follows: Data only.**

You need prepare a pre-encrypted Linux VHD and use the VHD to create an encrypted Linux VM on Azure.

Please refer to the following steps.

1.Create an Ubuntu 16.0.4 VM on Azure.

2.Prepare a pre-encrypted Linux VHD. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption#appendix).Notes: You need prepare the VHD on-premise.

3.Upload VHD to Azure.

4.Use [template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/201-encrypt-create-pre-encrypted-vm/) to create an encrypted Linux VM on Azure.